# compile libfacebookcpp on linux , 'StringBuilder' was not declared

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

when compile, it occurs an error:

```
PagingInfo.hpp:35: error: ‘StringBuilder’ was not declared in this scope.
```

I have inlude the right head file, but why compiler can not find the difinition of `StringBuilder`?

**Utils.hpp:**

```
#ifndef LIBFACEBOOKCPP_UTILS_H_
#define LIBFACEBOOKCPP_UTILS_H_

template<class TData, class TStr>
inline TData fromString(const TStr &str)
{
std::stringstream oss;
oss << str;
TData t;
oss >> t;
return t;
}

class StringBuilder
{
public:
inline operator const std::string () const
{
return oss.str();
}

private:
std::ostringstream oss;
};

#endif // LIBFACEBOOKCPP_UTILS_H_
```

**PagingInfo.hpp**

```
#ifndef LIBFACEBOOKCPP_PAGING_INFO_H_
#define LIBFACEBOOKCPP_PAGING_INFO_H_
#include "Utils.hpp"
namespace LibFacebookCpp
{

struct PagingInfo
{
PagingInfo(unsigned int offset_, unsigned int limit_) : offset(offset_), limit(limit_) { }

bool IsValid() const { return 0 != limit; }
void GetUri(Uri *uri) const
{
LIBFACEBOOKCPP_ASSERT(uri);
uri->query_params["limit"] = StringBuilder() << offset;
uri->query_params["offset"] = StringBuilder() << limit;
}
...
};

} // namespace LibFacebookCpp

#endif // LIBFACEBOOKCPP_PAGING_INFO_H_
```

Comment: No indentation? Please tell me your code doesn't actually look like that.  Also, why do you need a stringstream wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

When I add enough skeleton code to get this down to just your issue in [ideone](http://ideone.com/Nz2wVz), I get a different error:

> prog.cpp: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'StringBuilder() << ((const LibFacebookCpp::PagingInfo*)this)->LibFacebookCpp::PagingInfo::offset'

Your StringBuilder class does not have a << operator defined.  In order to use:

```
StringBuilder() << offset;
```

You will need to define one.

Between you and me, there are about 15 overloads of that operator for stringstreams (one for every primitive type).  It would be a massive waste of time to reimplement all of them.  Just use a `stringstream`.

Comment: oh,sorry, I omit that function for the code is too long.Thank you.I was compiling libfacebookcpp on Mac x86_64.So many errors.

Comment: Please include it then.  and seriously, reconsider using a stringbuilder wrapper.